# Why isn't the iterator not identifying the datatype of the multi-set in the called function?

Tags: c++11, multiset

I'm trying to find an optimized way to this problem-

https://www.codechef.com/KJCS2019/problems/TSHACK

```
int findanswer(int k,const multiset<pair<int,int> >&a2)
            {
                 int freq=0;
                     while(k>0)
                         {
                             multiset<pair<int,int> >::iterator itt=a2.end();
                             k-=itt.second;
                             a2.erase(itt);
                         ++freq;
                         }
                return freq;
            }
    int main()
{
            cin>>n>>q;
            map<int,int>a;
            multiset<pair<int,int> > a2;
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                int b;
                cin>>b;
                ++a[b];
            }
            for(auto it:a)
                a2.insert(make_pair(it.second,it.first));
            while(q--)
            {
                int k;
                cin>>k;
                int ans=findanswer(k,a2);
                cout<<ans<<endl;
            }
}
```

the error message :

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int findanswer(int, const std::multiset<std::pair<int, int> >&)':
prog.cpp:18:16: error: 'std::multiset<std::pair<int, int> >::iterator {aka struct std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<int, int> >}' has no member named 'second'
         k-=itt.second;
                ^
prog.cpp:19:21: error: passing 'const std::multiset<std::pair<int, int> >' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
         a2.erase(itt);
                 ^
```

As I said earlier, I want to know the reason why the iterator in the called function not identifying the datatype of the multiset.

Comment: it->second instead of it.second. The iterator has no second but it points to a pair

Comment: thanks @Klaus . I also want to why the erase function is displaying an error message.(I did the above changes).

Comment: Its because of the const in the header .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem:

You want to access the data which the iterator is pointing to and not the iterator itself. So you simply have to replace:

```
k-=itt->second;
```

Next problem:

```
int findanswer(int k,const multiset<pair<int,int> >&a2)
```

This defines your ref `a2` as `const`. As const you can't modify your multiset. So you have to remove `const` here.